# Type conversions for doubly linked list with custom iterator

Tags: c++, type-conversion, doubly-linked-list

As a coding exercise I've been trying to make a doubly linked list along with custom iterators. While testing, I noticed that there are a lot of errors to do with type conversion and I'm not quite sure how to fix them.

Below is my code:

```
template<typename Type>
class UnorderedList 
{
    private:
        int listsize;
        struct Node {
            Type data;
            Node * next;
            Node * previous;
            Node() {
                next = previous = nullptr;
                data = Type();
            }
        };
        Node * first;
        Node * last;
        Node * end_place; // empty node for end() function, not to be used or dereferenced
    public:
        // iterators
        class iterator {
            private:
                // internal iterator pointer
                Node * n_ptr;
            public:
                // iterator tags for compiler
                using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
                using difference_type   = std::ptrdiff_t;
                using value_type        = Node;
                using pointer           = Node *;
                using reference         = Node &;
                
                // iterator constructor
                iterator(Node * node) { n_ptr = node; }
                
                // iterator operator overloads for bidirectional_iterator
                reference operator * () { return n_ptr; }
                pointer operator -> () { return n_ptr; }
                iterator & operator ++ () { n_ptr = n_ptr -> next; return * this; }
                iterator operator ++ (int) { iterator temp = * this; ++(* this); return temp; }
                iterator & operator -- () { n_ptr = n_ptr -> previous; return * this; }
                iterator operator -- (int) { iterator temp = * this; --(* this); return temp; }
                friend bool operator == (const iterator & a, const iterator & b) { return (a.n_ptr == b.n_ptr); }
                friend bool operator != (const iterator & a, const iterator & b) { return (a.n_ptr != b.n_ptr); }
        };

        // begin() and end() returning iterators
        iterator begin() { return iterator(first); }
        iterator end() { return iterator(end_place); }
    
        // list constructors
        UnorderedList(int size) {
            Node * one = nullptr;
            Node * two = nullptr;
            two = new Node;
            two -> previous = one;
            first = two;
            for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
                two = new Node;
                one -> next = two;
                two -> previous = one;
            }
            last = two;
            end_place = new Node;
            end_place -> data = NULL;
            end_place -> previous = end_place -> next = nullptr;
            last -> next = end_place;
            listsize = size;
        }
        UnorderedList(int size, Type fill) {
            Node * one = nullptr;
            Node * two = nullptr;
            two = new Node;
            two -> previous = one;
            two -> data = fill;
            first = two;
            one = two;
            for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
                two = new Node;
                two -> data = fill;
                one -> next = two;
                two -> previous = one;
            }
            last = two;
            end_place = new Node;
            end_place -> data = Type();
            end_place -> previous = end_place -> next = nullptr;
            last -> next = end_place;
            listsize = size;
        }
        UnorderedList(int size, Type * values) {
            Node * one = nullptr;
            Node * two = nullptr;
            two = new Node;
            two -> previous = one;
            two -> data = * values;
            first = two;
            for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
                two = new Node;
                two -> data = * (values + i);
                one -> next = two;
                two -> previous = one;
            }
            last = two;
            end_place = new Node;
            end_place -> data = NULL;
            end_place -> previous = end_place -> next = nullptr;
            last -> next = end_place;
            listsize = size;
        }

        // member functions
        // return size of list; O(1)
        int size() { return listsize; }
        // return true if list is empty, false otherwise; O(1)
        bool empty() { return (listsize == 0); }
        // returns an iterator pointing to the node at the desired position; O(n)
        iterator get(int position) {
            if (position < listsize / 2) {
                // the position is in the first half of the list
                iterator it = begin();
                for (int i = 0; i < position; ++i) ++it;
                return it;
            }
            // the position is in the second half of the list
            iterator it(last);
            for (int i = 0; i < listsize - position - 1; ++i) --it;
            return it;
        }
        // edit the value of the node pointed to by the iterator; O(1)
        void edit(iterator it, Type value) {
            Node * node = * it;
            node -> data = value;
        }
        // push a new node to the front of the list; O(1)
        void push_front(Type value) {
            Node * newfront = new Node;
            newfront -> data = value;
            newfront -> next = first;
            first -> previous = newfront;
            newfront -> previous = nullptr;
            first = newfront;
            ++listsize;
        }
        // pop the front of the list if it is not empty, strong exception guarantee; O(1)
        void pop_front() {
            if (listsize == 0) {
                std::cerr << "Cannot pop empty list\n";
                return;
            }
            if (listsize == 1) {
                delete first;
                return;
            }
            Node * newfirst = first -> next;
            delete first;
            first = newfirst;
            first -> previous = nullptr;
            --listsize;
        }
        // push a new node to the back of the list; O(1)
        void push_back(Type value) {
            Node * newback = new Node;
            newback -> data = value;
            newback -> previous = last;
            last -> next = newback;
            newback -> next = end_place;
            last = newback;
            ++listsize;
        }
        // pop the back of the list if it is not empty, strong exception guarantee; O(1)
        void pop_back() {
            if (listsize == 0) {
                std::cerr << "Cannot pop empty list\n";
                return;
            }
            if (listsize == 1) {
                delete first;
                return;
            }
            Node * newlast = last -> previous;
            delete last;
            last = newlast;
            last -> next = nullptr;
            --listsize;
        }
        // insert a new node before the node pointed to by the iterator; O(1)
        void insert(iterator it, Type value) {
            if (it == begin()) { push_front(value); return; }
            if (it == end()) { push_back(value); return; }
            Node * before = & (* (--it));
            ++it;
            Node * after = & (* (++it));
            Node * inserted = new Node;
            inserted -> data = value;
            before -> next = inserted;
            after -> previous = inserted;
            inserted -> next = after;
            inserted -> previous = before;
            ++listsize;
        }
        // pop the node pointed to by it, strong exception guarantee
        void pop(iterator it) {
            if (it == begin()) { pop_front(); return; }
            if (it == end()) { pop_back(); return; }
            if (listsize == 0) {
                std::cerr << "Cannot pop empty list\n";
                return;
            }
            if (listsize == 1) {
                delete first;
                return;
            }
            Node * before = * (--it);
            ++it;
            Node * after = * (++it);
            before -> next = after;
            after -> previous = before;
            Node * deletenode = * it;
            delete deletenode;
        }
        void reverse(iterator from, iterator to) {
            if (from == to) return;
            vector<Type> v;
            int cnt = 0;
            for (iterator it = from, end = to; it != end; ++it) 
            {
                Node * curr = * it;
                v.push_back(curr.data);
                ++cnt;
            }
            std::reverse(v.begin(), v.end());
        }
        void reverse() {
            reverse(begin(), end());
        }
        UnorderedList operator + (UnorderedList & nextlist) {
            delete end_place;
            last -> next = nextlist.first;
            nextlist.first -> previous = last;
            return * this;
        }
        ~ UnorderedList () {
            Node * current = first;
            Node * next = current -> next;
            for (int i = 0; i < listsize; ++i) {
                delete current;
                current = next;
                next = current -> next;
            }
            delete first;
            delete last;
            delete end_place;
        }

        void display() {
            for (iterator it = begin(), eit = end(); it != eit; ++it) {
                Node * node = * it;
                cout << node -> data << (it == --eit ? "\n" : " <=> ");
            }
        }
};
```

The output when I build in VSCode (please note, the line numbers are off because I removed the include directives):

```
 *  Executing task: C/C++: g++ build active file 

Starting build...
/usr/bin/g++ -fdiagnostics-color=always -g /Users/ericssonlin/code/C++/template.cpp -o /Users/ericssonlin/code/C++/template
/Users/ericssonlin/code/C++/template.cpp:43:43: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
                using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
                                          ^
/Users/ericssonlin/code/C++/template.cpp:44:43: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
                using difference_type   = std::ptrdiff_t;
                                          ^
/Users/ericssonlin/code/C++/template.cpp:45:43: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
                using value_type        = Node;
                                          ^
/Users/ericssonlin/code/C++/template.cpp:46:43: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
                using pointer           = Node *;
                                          ^
/Users/ericssonlin/code/C++/template.cpp:47:43: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
                using reference         = Node &;
                                          ^
/Users/ericssonlin/code/C++/template.cpp:245:33: error: member reference base type 'UnorderedList::Node *' is not a structure or union
                v.push_back(curr.data);
                            ~~~~^~~~~
/Users/ericssonlin/code/C++/template.cpp:274:24: error: no viable conversion from 'UnorderedList<int>::Node' to 'UnorderedList<int>::Node *'
                Node * node = * it;
                       ^      ~~~~
/Users/ericssonlin/code/C++/template.cpp:284:10: note: in instantiation of member function 'UnorderedList<int>::display' requested here
    list.display();
         ^
/Users/ericssonlin/code/C++/template.cpp:53:50: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'UnorderedList<int>::Node' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'UnorderedList<int>::Node *'
                reference operator * () { return n_ptr; }
                                                 ^~~~~
/Users/ericssonlin/code/C++/template.cpp:274:31: note: in instantiation of member function 'UnorderedList<int>::iterator::operator*' requested here
                Node * node = * it;
                              ^
/Users/ericssonlin/code/C++/template.cpp:284:10: note: in instantiation of member function 'UnorderedList<int>::display' requested here
    list.display();
         ^
/Users/ericssonlin/code/C++/template.cpp:244:24: error: no viable conversion from 'UnorderedList<int>::Node' to 'UnorderedList<int>::Node *'
                Node * curr = * it;
                       ^      ~~~~
/Users/ericssonlin/code/C++/template.cpp:251:13: note: in instantiation of member function 'UnorderedList<int>::reverse' requested here
            reverse(begin(), end());
            ^
/Users/ericssonlin/code/C++/template.cpp:290:10: note: in instantiation of member function 'UnorderedList<int>::reverse' requested here
    list.reverse();
         ^
/Users/ericssonlin/code/C++/template.cpp:230:20: error: no viable conversion from 'UnorderedList<int>::Node' to 'UnorderedList<int>::Node *'
            Node * before = * (--it);
                   ^        ~~~~~~~~
/Users/ericssonlin/code/C++/template.cpp:294:10: note: in instantiation of member function 'UnorderedList<int>::pop' requested here
    list.pop(it);
         ^
/Users/ericssonlin/code/C++/template.cpp:232:20: error: no viable conversion from 'UnorderedList<int>::Node' to 'UnorderedList<int>::Node *'
            Node * after = * (++it);
                   ^       ~~~~~~~~
/Users/ericssonlin/code/C++/template.cpp:235:20: error: no viable conversion from 'UnorderedList<int>::Node' to 'UnorderedList<int>::Node *'
            Node * deletenode = * it;
                   ^            ~~~~
5 warnings and 7 errors generated.

Build finished with error(s).

 *  The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1). 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Comment: You seem to be using a rather old version of GCC, which is using an older version of the C++ standard as its base. You need to add the `-std=c++11` (or if GCC is *really* old `-std=c++1x`).

Comment: Many of the other errors are because you mix object and pointers to objects. A pointer to an object is not the object itself.

Comment: And for future questions, please learn how to create a [mre], with emphasis on the *minimal* part. Generally, don't write large chunks of code in one go without building or testing. Start with an empty `main` function. Build (with extra warning enabled, treated as errors) and if it builds cleanly then test. Then write a ***small*** part of code, build and test. Don't continue until it build cleanly, and passes all tests. This makes it much easier to write good, clean and working code. It also makes it much easier to debug if there's a problem.

Comment: You say that `operator *` should return a `Node &` (a.k.a. `reference`), which is good, but then you return `Node*`, which is bad. Also, the `+` operator does normally not modify any of its operands. And you have a double-delete issue in your destructor. (I think you wrote way too  much code at once.)

Comment: In the case it could be of some help, you can find [here](https://github.com/rlefevre1/Basic-structures-tutorials/blob/master/doublylinkedlist.h) a simple implementation of a doubly linked list with iterators, reverse iterators, const and non-const. (It's for the sole usage of understanding the concept, it's not intended to replace `std::list`)

Answer (score 1):

You are using an outdated compiler version.

Additionally, there were some minor bugs.

I fixed the and compiled the code with clang16 and gcc12.2 with -Wall and -Wpedantic.

This worked without warning. Please see here: https://godbolt.org/z/hj56vazW8

Please be aware. There are still semantic errors.

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

template<typename Type>
class UnorderedList
{
private:
    int listsize;
    struct Node {
        Type data;
        Node* next;
        Node* previous;
        Node() {
            next = previous = nullptr;
            data = Type();
        }
    };
    Node* first;
    Node* last;
    Node* end_place; // empty node for end() function, not to be used or dereferenced
public:
    // iterators
    class iterator {
    private:
        // internal iterator pointer
        Node* n_ptr;
    public:
        // iterator tags for compiler
        using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = Node;
        using pointer = Node*;
        using reference = Node&;

        // iterator constructor
        iterator(Node* node) { n_ptr = node; }

        // iterator operator overloads for bidirectional_iterator
        reference operator * () { return n_ptr; }
        pointer operator -> () { return n_ptr; }
        iterator& operator ++ () { n_ptr = n_ptr->next; return *this; }
        iterator operator ++ (int) { iterator temp = *this; ++(*this); return temp; }
        iterator& operator -- () { n_ptr = n_ptr->previous; return *this; }
        iterator operator -- (int) { iterator temp = *this; --(*this); return temp; }
        friend bool operator == (const iterator& a, const iterator& b) { return (a.n_ptr == b.n_ptr); }
        friend bool operator != (const iterator& a, const iterator& b) { return (a.n_ptr != b.n_ptr); }
    };

    // begin() and end() returning iterators
    iterator begin() { return iterator(first); }
    iterator end() { return iterator(end_place); }

    // list constructors
    UnorderedList(int size) {
        Node* one = nullptr;
        Node* two = nullptr;
        two = new Node;
        two->previous = one;
        first = two;
        for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
            two = new Node;
            one->next = two;
            two->previous = one;
        }
        last = two;
        end_place = new Node;
        end_place->data = {};
        end_place->previous = end_place->next = nullptr;
        last->next = end_place;
        listsize = size;
    }
    UnorderedList(int size, Type fill) {
        Node* one = nullptr;
        Node* two = nullptr;
        two = new Node;
        two->previous = one;
        two->data = fill;
        first = two;
        one = two;
        for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
            two = new Node;
            two->data = fill;
            one->next = two;
            two->previous = one;
        }
        last = two;
        end_place = new Node;
        end_place->data = Type();
        end_place->previous = end_place->next = nullptr;
        last->next = end_place;
        listsize = size;
        }
    UnorderedList(int size, Type* values) {
        Node* one = nullptr;
        Node* two = nullptr;
        two = new Node;
        two->previous = one;
        two->data = *values;
        first = two;
        for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
            two = new Node;
            two->data = *(values + i);
            one->next = two;
            two->previous = one;
        }
        last = two;
        end_place = new Node;
        end_place->data = NULL;
        end_place->previous = end_place->next = nullptr;
        last->next = end_place;
        listsize = size;
    }

    // member functions
    // return size of list; O(1)
    int size() { return listsize; }
    // return true if list is empty, false otherwise; O(1)
    bool empty() { return (listsize == 0); }
    // returns an iterator pointing to the node at the desired position; O(n)
    iterator get(int position) {
        if (position < listsize / 2) {
            // the position is in the first half of the list
            iterator it = begin();
            for (int i = 0; i < position; ++i) ++it;
            return it;
        }
        // the position is in the second half of the list
        iterator it(last);
        for (int i = 0; i < listsize - position - 1; ++i) --it;
        return it;
    }
    // edit the value of the node pointed to by the iterator; O(1)
    void edit(iterator it, Type value) {
        Node* node = *it;
        node->data = value;
    }
    // push a new node to the front of the list; O(1)
    void push_front(Type value) {
        Node* newfront = new Node;
        newfront->data = value;
        newfront->next = first;
        first->previous = newfront;
        newfront->previous = nullptr;
        first = newfront;
        ++listsize;
    }
    // pop the front of the list if it is not empty, strong exception guarantee; O(1)
    void pop_front() {
        if (listsize == 0) {
            std::cerr << "Cannot pop empty list\n";
            return;
        }
        if (listsize == 1) {
            delete first;
            return;
        }
        Node* newfirst = first->next;
        delete first;
        first = newfirst;
        first->previous = nullptr;
        --listsize;
    }
    // push a new node to the back of the list; O(1)
    void push_back(Type value) {
        Node* newback = new Node;
        newback->data = value;
        newback->previous = last;
        last->next = newback;
        newback->next = end_place;
        last = newback;
        ++listsize;
    }
    // pop the back of the list if it is not empty, strong exception guarantee; O(1)
    void pop_back() {
        if (listsize == 0) {
            std::cerr << "Cannot pop empty list\n";
            return;
        }
        if (listsize == 1) {
            delete first;
            return;
        }
        Node* newlast = last->previous;
        delete last;
        last = newlast;
        last->next = nullptr;
        --listsize;
    }
    // insert a new node before the node pointed to by the iterator; O(1)
    void insert(iterator it, Type value) {
        if (it == begin()) { push_front(value); return; }
        if (it == end()) { push_back(value); return; }
        Node* before = &(*(--it));
        ++it;
        Node* after = &(*(++it));
        Node* inserted = new Node;
        inserted->data = value;
        before->next = inserted;
        after->previous = inserted;
        inserted->next = after;
        inserted->previous = before;
        ++listsize;
    }
    // pop the node pointed to by it, strong exception guarantee
    void pop(iterator it) {
        if (it == begin()) { pop_front(); return; }
        if (it == end()) { pop_back(); return; }
        if (listsize == 0) {
            std::cerr << "Cannot pop empty list\n";
            return;
        }
        if (listsize == 1) {
            delete first;
            return;
        }
        Node* before = *(--it);
        ++it;
        Node* after = *(++it);
        before->next = after;
        after->previous = before;
        Node* deletenode = *it;
        delete deletenode;
    }
    void reverse(iterator from, iterator to) {
        if (from == to) return;
        vector<Type> v;
        //int cnt = 0;
        for (iterator it = from, end = to; it != end; ++it)
        {
            Node* curr = *it;
            v.push_back(curr->data);
            //++cnt;
        }
        std::reverse(v.begin(), v.end());
    }
    void reverse() {
        reverse(begin(), end());
    }
    UnorderedList operator + (UnorderedList& nextlist) {
        delete end_place;
        last->next = nextlist.first;
        nextlist.first->previous = last;
        return *this;
    }
    ~UnorderedList() {
        Node* current = first;
        Node* next = current->next;
        for (int i = 0; i < listsize; ++i) {
            delete current;
            current = next;
            next = current->next;
        }
        delete first;
        delete last;
        delete end_place;
    }

    void display() {
        for (iterator it = begin(), eit = end(); it != eit; ++it) {
            Node* node = *it;
            cout << node->data << (it == --eit ? "\n" : " <=> ");
        }
    }
};
int main() {
        UnorderedList<int> uol(10);
}
```